# Screenshot in Cypress happens too soon

Tags: cypress

For some reason Cypress is not taking a screenshot after the new page loads after clicking on menu item inside of dropdown menu.

```
it.only('2.4 - Press "My Settings" on the top right corner - "My Settings" screen is displayed.', () => {
  cy.login()

  cy.get('body div button[data-cy=usermenubutton]')
    .click()
    .get('body div ul li[data-my=mySettings]')
    .contains('My Settings')
    .click()
    .screenshot()
})
```

It runs correctly, I can see it click on My Settings and that new page loads up, but it has already taken the screenshot by then. What is happening here? Keep in mind I am brand new to Cypress.

I tried doing the following:

```
it.only('2.4 - Press "My Settings" on the top right corner - "My Settings" screen is displayed.', () => {
  cy.login()

  cy.get('body div button[data-cy=usermenubutton]')
    .click()
    .get('body div ul li[data-my=mySettings]')
    .contains('My Settings')
    .click()

  cy.get('[data-cy=headerTitle]')
    .should('be.visible')
    .screenshot()
})
```

When I do it this way I get an error:

```
expected '<vid.sc-gsDKAQ.eaXakP.MuiBox-root>' to be 'visible'

This element <vid.sc-gsDKAQ.eaXakP.MuiBox-root> is not visible because it has CSS property: position: fixed and it's being covered by another element:
```

When I try doing it this way:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=headerTitle]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .screenshot()
```

I get a poor screenshot, it's just the area of the new page and not the whole page, no heard, no sidebar and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wait for the page you want to take a screenshot of to load. To do so, add a assertion to check if the "My Settings" screen has properly loaded before you call `screenshot()`. I usually check for an element that should only be visible in the target page to actually be visible before firing my screenshot:

```js
it.only('2.4 - Press "My Settings" on the top right corner - "My Settings" screen is displayed.', () => {
  cy.login()

  cy.get('body div button[data-cy=usermenubutton]')
    .click()
    .get('body div ul li[data-my=mySettings]')
    .contains('My Settings')
    .click()

  cy.get('selector_of_an_element_only_visible_in_My_Settings')
    .should('be.visible')
    .screenshot()
})
```

As stated in the docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should#Timeouts), `should()`, like other cy commands, will continue to retry its assertion until it passes or until it times out.

---

If you're confident on the element you're asserting on and the screenshot still happens too fast, you should consider using `cy.wait()` and pause the test for 1 second.

```js
cy.get('[data-cy=headerTitle]')
  .should('be.visible')
  .wait(1000)
  .screenshot()
```

Comment: I shared why your answer did not work for me in my OP.

Comment: Could you try a different element? Like a button or an input that's more easily identifiable and tied to your My Settings screen? The selector for the element you chose suggests it might be a headerTitle that will be available on all pages and only its text content will change.